# Firebase: Delete files in Cloud Starage using Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to delete all files, related to some specific entry in `Realtime Database`, from `Cloud Storage` on the entry deletion, using `Cloud Functions`. My functions looks as fallows:

```
exports.onDeleteRequest = functions.database.ref('/requests/{requestid}/').onDelete(event => {
    const storage = functions.config().firebase.storageBucket;
    const userId = event.data.previous.child('uid').val();
    const requestId = event.params.requestid;
    const path = storage + '/photos/' + userId + '/' + requestId;
    console.log('path: ', path);
    return gcs.bucket(path).delete().then(function() {
            console.log("Files removed");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Failed removing files", error);
        });
});
```

But, I continue getting following error in log:

```
Failed removing files { ApiError: Not Found
    at Object.parseHttpRespBody (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:192:30)
    at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:132:18)
    at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:465:12
    at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:182:7)
    at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
  code: 404,
  errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found' } ],
  response: undefined,
  message: 'Not Found' }
```

`path: photos/gRplE2ujnIb93Ji5HSzEj3O4i3d2/-L-DHkKMhvLH9l6dWmR2`

All subfolders are 100% existing at the time of the function execution. Can anyone help?

I apologize for asking the question, that, without a doubt, was asked before in one way or another, but I didn't find any suggestion of how to solve this issue or why does it occurs in the first place.

Comment: FYI you can access the cloud storage api more easily via the admin SDK where it will properly initialize the cloud storage SDK using the default credentials for your project. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start

Comment: @DougStevenson Finally, I've managed to get the desired behavior using Admin SDK, but not in the best possible way. I've done it with the `deleteFiles` method with the [path] as the _prefix_ parameter, but, considering I need to remove the whole _bucket_ related to the db entry, it's seems like an overhead. When I try to call `admin.storage().bucket(path).delete()`, I keep getting **ApiError: Not Found**. Any thoughts?

Comment: You managed to solve this issue?

Comment: @NickolasM You can try passing the storage bucket inside `bucket(bucketLocation)` and not the `path`. This worked for me `admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket).file(object.name).delete()`.